# Resetting the UI of phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there any way to reset the font size without accessing the UI/program? I accidentally changed the font size a little too big and now all the UI is messed up and I can't see anything (not even a button) in phpstorm.

Comment: I have not tryed it, but maybe you can delete all the configuration. For phpstorm 7.1.0 this link may help you to find the config files
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html

Comment: Yes -- backup and delete IDE-wide settings (on Windows 7 it would be `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde70`). After starting from scratch yiu may recover most of the config files back from backup (while IDE is closed, of course).

Comment: Alternatively, just search trough config files for "font" and/or "size" words (in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde70\config\options` for Windows 7 and PhpStorm v7) and look for a huge number and reset it to some normal value (e.g. 10 or 12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <application>
      <component name="UISettings">
        <option name="FONT_SIZE" value="16" />
        <option name="OVERRIDE_NONIDEA_LAF_FONTS" value="true" />
        <option name="SHOW_DIRECTORY_FOR_NON_UNIQUE_FILENAMES" value="true" />
      </component>
    </application>
```

Nevermind found it! Its located in C:>users\username.WebIde70\config\options
Under ui.lnf.xml.

Comment: Just another answer , knowing the above is the correct way.Press Ctrl Alt S , then long press Arrow UP,, then long press Arrow left so the cursor will be on Appearance and behavior. Now press one by one following keys -> Enter , Arrow down,TAB,TAB,TAB,TAB,TAB,Ctrl A  then  Type 22[Any size] and hit Enter. :P